# How do I show that $ \langle u, v \rangle = \langle u, \lambda u + \mu u \rangle = \langle v, \lambda u + \mu v \rangle$ if $\mu \ne 0 \ne \lambda $?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Q:** Let $V$ be a vector space over the file $K$ and let $u, v \in V$. Suppose that $(u,v)$ is linearly independent.

Assume that $\lambda \ne 0 \ne \mu$. Show that in this case $ \langle u, v \rangle = \langle u, \lambda u + \mu u \rangle = \langle v, \lambda u + \mu v \rangle$.

**Attempt**: Ok first I'm trying to understand what all this means. I understand that $\langle u, v \rangle$ is the spanning set of (u,v) i.e. all the vectors that can be written as linear combinations of (u,v)? So if $\lambda \ne 0 \ne \mu$ and $ (u,v) $ are linearly independent then that means what? How do I go about answering this question? I am more than slightly confused.

Comment: I think there may be something wrong in the second equality; shouldn't $\langle u, \lambda u + \mu u \rangle$ be $\langle u, \lambda u + \mu v \rangle$ (i.e. the last $u$ should actually be a $v$?)

Comment: One of the things you're asked to prove is the statement
$$\forall \lambda,\mu\in K\left(\lambda \neq 0 \neq \mu\implies \{au+bv\colon a,b\in K\}=\{\alpha u+\beta (\lambda u+\mu v)\colon \alpha ,\beta \in K\}\right)$$

Comment: I think you may have messed $\;u\,,\,v\;$ in your question, @Siyanda . Be careful since this makes the question confusing. Also don't use $\;\langle,\rangle\;$ as notation for Span$\;\{\}\;$ since this is usually used in linear algebra for inner product and can be, again, confusing.

Comment: You should show that $u$ and $\lambda u + \mu v$ are in the span of $u$ and $v$ (trivial) and that $u$ and $v$ are in the span of $u$ and $\lambda u + \mu v$ (this uses the assumption that $\mu \neq 0$).

Comment: @DonAntonio the $\langle, \rangle$ notation was what was used in the question. Maybe that changes things?

Answer (score 1):

You wanna show span$\{u,v\}$ is exactly the same as span$\{u,\lambda u+\mu v\}$. This means any vector $x$ which can be represented as $x=au+bv$ can also be uniquely expressed as $x=cu+d(\lambda u+\mu v)$. This is easy by simple calculation. That is,
$$c=a-\frac{\lambda b}{\mu}$$
$$d=\frac{b}{\mu}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\begin{align*}u\,,\,\lambda u+\mu v&\in\;\text{ Span}\{u,v\}\\
v=-\frac\lambda\mu u+\frac1\mu\left(\lambda u+\mu v\right)\implies u,v&\in\;\text{ Span}\{u\,,\,\lambda u+\mu v\}\end{align*}$$